# some troubles with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

there is no problem with this command:

```
sed -i -E '/ChannelSetting=/{:loop /\\/{s/\\//g;N;bloop};s/(ChannelSetting=).*/\1/}' build_config/resource.properties
```

but this command will occur "sed: -e expression #1, char 30: Unmatched {":

```
sed -i -E "/ChannelSetting=/{:loop /\\/{s/\\//g;N;bloop};s/(ChannelSetting=).*/\1/}" build_config/resource.properties
```

What's the difference with " and ' caused the error?
Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) you will understand the difference of both.

Comment: thanks,I have solved this problem.

Comment: ok good to know that @Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second case, escape character '\' is interpreted by your shell.
Use the echo command to understand the difference:

```
>> echo "/ChannelSetting=/{:loop /\\/{s/\\//g;N;bloop};s/(ChannelSetting=).*/\1/}" 
/ChannelSetting=/{:loop /\/{s/\//g;N;bloop};s/(ChannelSetting=).*/\1/}
```

Note that '\' appear only once at each occurrence: missing ones have been interpreted by your shell as an escape character. So sed command does only receive the second '\' of each occurence.

```
>> echo '/ChannelSetting=/{:loop /\\/{s/\\//g;N;bloop};s/(ChannelSetting=).*/\1/}'
/ChannelSetting=/{:loop /\\/{s/\\//g;N;bloop};s/(ChannelSetting=).*/\1/}
```

As you can see, in second case, all character are sent as is to sed.

Usually you need to mix both type of string delimiter:

- ' (for special character as'\')
- " (in order to interpret some shell variables):

Example:

```
myMatch='ChannelSetting='
sed -i -E "/$myMatch/"'{:loop /\\/{s/\\//g;N;bloop};s/('$myMatch').*/\1/}'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the behavior of the Bash-shell, loog at the difference of these two outputs:

```
root@Server:~# echo "\\"
\
root@Server:~# echo '\\'
\\
```

The backslash in "" quotes the next char, the backslash in '' is only a backslash.

Btw., it's the same with vars:

```
root@Server:~# XX=12
root@Server:~# echo "$XX"
12
root@Server:~# echo '$XX'
$XX
```